# Stop Excel From Automatically Creating a Table When Mapping XML Elements

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, xml

When I drag a single-node from `//root/node` onto the spreadsheet a table is not automatically created and I get the drop-down option to place the heading on the left or top etc.

However, when I drag a single-node from `//root/element/child/grandchild` a table is automatically created, even though the single node (the grandchild) has no other child nodes. (However, child nodes do exist for other grandchildren under the child).

Given the way data is displayed in the schema I would like to stop the table from automatically creating so I can lay out the nodes I need by row, by dropping them in one-by-one underneath each other.

**For illustration**

`/CoPolicy/CoEffectiveDt` and `/CoPolicy/CoExpirationDate` when dropped in Excel shows like this:

[image]

However, `/CoPolicy/CoLobs/CoLob/GLPolInput/GlEachOccLmt` (et. al.) shows like the below even though they have only 1 item each and will always have only 1 item.

[image]

How can I get the 2nd example to stop automatically creating the table and to allow me to place each single-node in a row format like example 1? All my tricks have failed so far.